# Android: Leaking memory after using Bitmap.createBitmap

Tags: android, android-memory

After many reading of related posts, I haven't found a working solution to this problem yet.
When my application resizing a Bitmap object, by using the static method: `Bitmap.createBitmap`, I think it leaks memory.

The method which I suspect for memory leaking:

```
HashMap < Integer , BoardImage > boardsImages = new HashMap<Integer, BoardImage>();

public synchronized void addBoard(BoardImage b) {

    // check if the board isn't already exists
    if (boardsImages.get( b.getBoardNumber() ) == null){ 
        parent.addButton(b.getBoardNumber()); // add new button
        numOfButtons++;
    }

    // resize the image to strech over the canves
    int newWidth = getWidth(), // the new width of the image
        newHeight = getHeight(),// the new height of the image
        width = b.getBoardBitmap().getWidth(),// the old width of the image
        height = b.getBoardBitmap().getHeight();// the old height of the image

    // resize the image
    Bitmap resized = resizeBitmap(newWidth, newHeight,width,height,b.getBoardBitmap());
    // update the object
    b.recycleBitmap();
    b.setBoardBitmap(resized);

    boardsImages.put(b.getBoardNumber(), b);
}

public Bitmap resizeBitmap(int newWidth, int newHeight,int curWidth,int curHeight,Bitmap img){

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / curWidth;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / curHeight;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, curWidth, curHeight, matrix, true);

    return resized;
}
```

BoardImage class (part of it):

```
transient private Bitmap boardBitmap = null;
public void setBoardBitmap(Bitmap b){       
    boardBitmap = b;
}

public Bitmap getBoardBitmap(){
    return boardBitmap;
}

public void recycleBitmap(){
    boardBitmap.recycle();
    boardBitmap = null;
}
```

With debugger, after the line which calls `Bitmap.createBitmap`, i get this message at Logcat:
`Grow heap (frag case) to 8.169MB for 1818612-byte allocation`

When the heap size reaches its limit (which is set to 32MB in my AVD), the program crashes with `OutOfMemory` exception.

If more code is needed let me know, Thanks!

Comment: Calculate the sample size..Follow tutorial in developers.android.com

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. as @Pragnani suggested follow the docs.

Comment: I'm not sure its size problem since the images are quite small (467x503 JPG, ~20KB).
If I don't resize them everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, before returning:

```
img.recycle();
img = null;
```

Comment: Are you recycling the resized bitmap after you used it?

Comment: Yes. 
The thing is that logcat shows the heap grow immediately after Bitmap.createBitmap() is finished.

Comment: I don't think that message alone is a problem, it is only saying that the heap is growing. Does the OutOfMemory happen just after that message? Can you post the logcat?

Comment: No, OutOfMemory happens if the app exceeds the 30MB of heap. This will occur only after it receives enough images from the server (each image will cause the heap to increase by around 2MB).
NOTE that if I DON'T resize the image - the heap won't grow at all

Comment: I still don't think the heap growing is an issue, the problem is that you are leaking the resized bitmap... If you post all the code related would be easier to help! You could decrease the bitmap sampling size (search for BitmapFactory.Options), but eventually the OOM will happen.